# How to prevent long text from flowing out of a container

Tags: html, css

How can I use CSS to wrap long words such as wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Instead of them flowing out of a div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `white-space: pre-line;`, it should break long words / strings.

Comment: Found this for a different example, works great for sentences. mint