# Preventing long words from flowing out of Div without using CSS break-word

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a div and all the long words (without spaces) flow outside the div.

Please don't mark the question as a duplicate of [How to prevent long text from flowing out of a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048858/how-to-prevent-long-text-from-flowing-out-of-a-container) or [Long words are flowing out of the box - How to prevent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261738/long-words-are-flowing-out-of-the-box-how-to-prevent), where the problem is solved by using `word-wrap: break-word;`.

The disadvantage of `word-wrap: break-word;` is that it also breaks short words which are at the edge of the div, in a way that disrupts the flow of the text. I want short words to remain the way they are and only break the long words. Is it possible to implement this? How do other websites handle it?

Comment: What about putting that div or p tag inside a div then give that particular tag which is inside a margin?

Comment: This looks like a huge flaw or limitation with `break-word`. Is JavaScript or jQuery an option? You could identify words that may be longer than the width of the container, and wrap them in a span tag that has `break-word` applied to it. Not sure if there's an existing jQuery plug-in that does this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it also breaks short words which are at the edge of the div

That's not true...`word-wrap: break-word;` shouldn't do that.
Perhaps you're confusing this with the `word-break: break-all;` property (which doesn't work in all browsers).

See this jsfiddle for a comparison: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Snu8B/3/

For firefox you could try the [hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/hyphens) property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to "hide" the words you can play with overflow:hidden

```
.mydiv {
   height  : youchoose;
   width   : youchoose;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Otherwise:

```
word-wrap : normal|break-word;
normal    : Break words only at allowed break points
break-word: Allows unbreakable words to be broken

word-break: normal|break-all|hyphenate;
normal    : Breaks non-CJK scripts according to their own rules
break-all : Lines may break between any two characters for non-CJK scripts
hyphenate : Words may be broken at an appropriate hyphenation point
```